# C# File Algorithm Optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm

Just write the below algorithm for my friend who is operating a call center and want to format his file names and move a directory to acording to months and dates. But the call center has over 3.5M files and seems like the program worked for 12 hours and just process less than 20gb

So is there any way exist for optimizing below algorithm,

```
class Program
{        
    // How much deep to scan. (of course you can also pass it to the method)
    const int HowDeepToScan = 20;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessDir(@"E:\Hard Disk 2\", 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Islem Bitmistir");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ProcessDir(string sourceDir, int recursionLvl)
    {
        if (recursionLvl <= HowDeepToScan)
        {
            ChangeDirectories(sourceDir);

            // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
            string[] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
            foreach (string subdir in subdirEntries)
                // Do not iterate through reparse points
                if ((File.GetAttributes(subdir) &
                     FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) !=
                         FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                    ProcessDir(subdir+@"\",recursionLvl + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeDirectories(string givenPath)
    {
        DataTable resultSet = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection callCenterConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=CallCenter;Data Source=.");
        //Directory of mp3s
        string sourceDir = givenPath;
        //Get the files inside that directory
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        callCenterConnection.Open();
        //Iterate through those files
        foreach (string fullFileName in fileEntries)
        {
            //Get the file name without path and extension
            string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileName);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 ID,Time,Tel,AgentID FROM ResultTable WHERE ID=" + fileNameWithoutExtension, callCenterConnection);
            adapter.Fill(resultSet);
        }
        adapter.Dispose();
        if (resultSet.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in resultSet.Rows)
            {
                DateTime fileDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Time"]);
                if (!File.Exists(@"E:\Ses Dosyalari" + @"\" + fileDate.Year + @"\" + fileDate.Month + @"\" + Convert.ToString(dr["Time"]).Replace(":", ".") + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["Tel"]) + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["AgentID"]) + ".mp3"))
                {
                    File.Move(sourceDir + Convert.ToString(dr["ID"]) + ".mp3", @"E:\Ses Dosyalari" + @"\" + fileDate.Year + @"\" + fileDate.Month + @"\" + Convert.ToString(dr["Time"]).Replace(":", ".") + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["Tel"]) + " - " + Convert.ToString(dr["AgentID"]) + ".mp3");
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ResultTable SET Used = 1 WHERE ID="+Convert.ToString(dr["ID"]), callCenterConnection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
        callCenterConnection.Close();
        resultSet.Clear();
        resultSet.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to ask this on [`Codereview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You monster, you ran this for 12 hours? Making separate select and update requests for each file?

Comment: Why do you create a new database connection for each directory ?

Comment: You should run the performance profiler (Jetbrains or VS Team system) to measure the spots in your code; in the case you can't find them yourself.

Comment: Yes I do if I were to seperate the update and delete is that help? and how can I do that?

Comment: Also - maybe it's the network latency that is giving You problems...

Comment: SQL server and program running on the same server, so there is no latency for queries but will optimize connection usage, will use one connection for all queries if thats help

Comment: Get a list of all your file names first, pass it to db (1 query), get dataset from db, check if all files from db exist in your folder/move/whatever, update records for those files (1 query). So you'll end up with 2 queries instead of 3.5M*2 (worst case), not bad, eh?

Comment: Actually why don't you select everything from the `ResultTable` first and then check if it exists in your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are pretty good that the bottleneck is not your code's performance characteristics, but the network between the locations.

That said there's plenty of room for optimization in the second method in particular.

First, always work with data from a database in bulk, checking for one record's existence at a time is costly, read them all at once and put them into a list.  Iterate over said list to perform your move/status updates.

Second, you're concatenating strings with `+` use `String.Format` or `String.Concat` instead (or a `StringBuilder` if that's more to your liking)

Being that the most taxed resource in this operation is the network, I'd suggest using a compression library to wrap up all of the files for a directory (at least) shipping that to the remote site and having a process unpack it there and send back a completion notification. Sending less is more.

Comment: Thanks a lot mlorbetske, Maksim Vi and Aphelion I know the code is the thing seperate one programmer from others and I will optimize query part by using bulks, will use just one connection string and will move files from usb disk to the server seems like it also effect performance